# submenu in menu is displayed under the content in web form with master page, how to solve this

Tags: html, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a master page with menu which has sub menu's. i have a web form which is added to this master page, this form has a table with some UI. problem is sub menu is displaying under the contnet page not displaying on the page. actually it is hiding under content page.

What property to i need to set to display sub menu on the content page.

```
     Css  for menu is 
     .nav {
float:left;
display:block;
left:220px;
position:absolute;
     }

     .nav ul

     {
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px; }

     .nav li
     {
position:relative;
width:150px;
background-color:#333333;
text-align:center;
border-right:1px soloid white;
line-height:30px;
height:30px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin-right:1px;
}


     .nav li ul {
list-style:none;
visibility:hidden;
margin:0px;
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:0; }

     .nav li ul li {
position:relative;
float:none;
width:150px;
height:auto;
padding-left:1px;
border-top:1px solid white;
margin:0;
text-align:left; }

     .nav a
{

text-decoration:none;   
color:#FFFFFF; }
     .nav li:hover ul {
visibility:visible; }


     .nav li:hover {
background-color:#3300FF;
font-size:1.3em; }
```

Menu code is

```
     <div class="nav">

     <ul >
            <li> <a href="#">Home</a>    </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Products</a>  

                     <ul>
                            <li>
                                    <a>List of Products</a> 
                           </li>
                            <li>
                                 <a> List of Products </a>
                              </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>
                                List of Products
                                </a>

                            </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Services</a>    </li>
            <li> <a href="#">AboutUs</a>    </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Careers</a>    </li>

            <li> <a href="#">Contact Us</a>    </li>

     </ul>

     </div>
```

All this code is placed in a master page in asp.net

Comment: provide some html and css which you are using for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

I need too see the code and the css.
But it's lool like css problem.
try to set the sub-menu as `position: relative;` and try to set `z-index: 10`.

**Edit**
Because you added the code I see that you don't need to set position relative. You just have to set `z-index:10;` to `.nav`